# Bootstrap modal show up twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my rails app, I'm using Twitter bootstrap.

Before, everything was working fine, but suddenly the modal start showing twice.
I have no idea what's going on.. My code is like below.

## devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Terms of Service", terms_in_modal_path, {:class => "show-terms", :remote => true}
```

## pages_controller

```
def terms_in_modal
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

## terms_in_modal.js.erb

```
$("#signup-modal").html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => "terms_in_modal") %>');
$('#show-terms').modal('show');
```

## _terms_in_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="show-terms" class="modal hide fade in">
...
</div>
```

After I click the link, two modals show up and the output html is like below.

```
<div id="signup-modal">
  <div id="show-terms" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>

<div id="show-terms" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
    ...
</div>
```

Edit1

In my staging app on Heroku, the modal work fine.
Weird thing is, I didn't edit anything relate to modal and signup page after I push on heroku last time.
I recently change the OS to Mountain Lion, so it may relate to the OS.

Edit2

I did "git push staging master" and tried if the modal will work fine, and it is working fine.
Very weird..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this in your local environment most likely because your compiled assets that you need for Heroku are conflicting with the assets Rails includes on the fly when your in a development environment.  To prevent this, you most likely need to just `rm -rf public/assets` to remove your precompiled assets.  You should make sure to recompile them before every push to Heroku.

Comment: I tried your solution and now modal is working fine on my local server, thanks. I think my carrierwave and environment setting has something wrong. Cause I keep getting error when I try assets:precompile. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to check the green arrow if my answer was the solution to your question.  :D